# Parsing weirdly structured XML with lxml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I have a number of XML files that I need to parse. I've written some code that works, but is ugly, and I'd like to get some advice from people more experienced with XML than I am.

First of all, I might be using some terms in the wrong context, because my experience with XML is limited. By element, unless specified otherwise, I mean something like this:

```
 <root>
  <element>
   ...
  </element>
  <element>
   ...
  </element>
 </root>
```

Anyway, each file consist of a number of elements, with a number of child elements (obviously). What stumps me is that the relevant values need to be accessed in four different ways;

1) Node text:

```
<tag>value</tag>
```

2) Attribute:

```
<tag attribute="value"></tag>
```

3) A value "hidden" inside a tag ("true" in this case):

```
<tag><boolean.true/></tag>
```

4) Values inside tags of the same name ("tagA"), but with "grandparent" tags with different names ("tag1" and "tag2"), all within the same element. "tagA" is of no use to me, instead I will be looking for "tag1" and "tag2".

```
<element>
   <tag1><tagA>value</tagA><tag1>
   <tag2><tagA>value</tagA></tag2>
</element>
```

At the moment I have a dictionary with each file as a key. The values are dictionaries with the keys "attribute", "node text", "tag" and "parent element".

Example:

```
{'file1.xml' : 'attributes' : {'Person': 'Id', 'Car' : 'Color'},
               'node text': ['Name', 'Address'],
}
```

Where "Person" and "Car" are tags, and "Id" and "Color" are attribute names.

This makes it easy to iterate over all elements and inspect each tag, and if there is a match in the dictionary (if elem.tag in dict['file1.xml']['attributes']), extract the value.

So as I said, the code works, but I don't like my solution. Also, not all the elements have all the child elements (for example, a Person might not own a car, then that tag will be missing altogether), and I need to give assign those values "None". Right now I get all the tags that should exist for every element in each file, turn them into a set, then check the difference between those and the set of tags that I've actually extracted values from for that element. Again, the code is pretty ugly.

Hopefully this mess makes some sense.

edit:

I used J.F. Sebastian's suggestion of storing the xpath to each value in a dictionary with the field name as the key and xpath as value.

Comment: How do you use `lxml`?. `etree.fromstring("<tag></boolean.true></tag>")` produces `XMLSyntaxError`. And `tree = etree.parse(StringIO("<tag></boolean.true></tag>"),parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))` eats `</boolean.true>` i.e., `etree.tostring(tree)` is `'<tag/>'`.

Comment: `parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)`
    `doc = etree.parse(fs, parser)`
    `root = doc.getroot()`
    `for child in root:`

Comment: Do you see `</boolean.true>` in the output: `print etree.tostring(doc)`?

Comment: Yeah, but I realized #3 in the OP is wrong though, this is what it actually looks like:

`<DTBoolean><DTBoolean.true/></DTBoolean>`

Comment: you could [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7894357/edit) your question to correct #3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could streamline your *input* code by using `xpath` expressions relative your element instead of a complex data-structure e.g., #1-4 cases:

1. tag/text()
2. tag/@attribute
3. name(DTBoolean/*[1])
4. (tag1|tag2)/*/text()

What *output* data-structure to use depends on how do you like it to be used in your code later. You could start with a structure that is most convenient for your current code. And evolve it to a more general solution later when you better understand the requirements.

> I output it to csv, where each element is one row in the csv file. 
>   ...
>   I use a defaultdict to store the elements and then store those in a list before I output them to csv.

You could use ordinary dict and csv.DictWriter(fieldnames=xpathdict.keys()):

```
# for each element
row_dict = dict.fromkeys(xpathdict.keys())
...
# for each key 
row_dict[key] = element.xpath(xpathdict[key]) or None
...
dictwriter.writerow(row_dict)
```

Where `xpathdict` is a mapping between field names and corresponding xpath expressions. For generality you could store function objects `f(element) -> csv field` instead of/in addition to xpath exprs.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but how would I then specify which type each child element is? Don't I still have to use something like the dictionary I'm currently using to say "Person is an attribute, Name is node text, etc..."?

Comment: @feasible_successor: It depends on how you use in a later code. Forget about input for a moment. What do you with the data once you get it? You say some data are optional what your code does in this case?

Comment: I output it to csv, where each element is one row in the csv file. So I end up with one csv file for each XML file.
If by optional data you mean the missing child elements, then I just check which child elements every element _have_, and compare it to which child elements it _should_ have. The missing child elements get a value of None. 
I use a defaultdict to store the elements and then store those in a list before I output them to csv.

Comment: I'm testing something based on what you said. I still have a dictionary with each file as a key, but the values are xpaths to all the relevant values. So I iterate over all the children to the root and then iterate over every xpath for that file. This means I will get a None value if the child element doesn't exist, which is nice, and so far the code is much prettier.
I need to do some further testing to see if this is a viable solution though, but thanks for giving me the idea!

Comment: @feasible_successor: you should probably add that info to your question. I've added outline on how to use the xpath exprs. to produce csv.

Comment: I did a combination of my new method and yours (didn't know about DictWriter, very handy!). It might not be an optimal solution, but it works, and the code is much better (reduced by 100 lines!). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think #3 is legal XML because there's no opening tag associated with  and even if it's somewhere else, it wouldn't be properly nested in that example.  The expression  will be interpreted as a closing tag because of the `<` character.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, unfortunately nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you'd want to take something like this:

```
<root>
  <element>
    <text_attribute>Some Text</text_attribute>
    <attribute var="blah"/>
    <bool_attribute><boolean.true/></bool_attribute>
  </element>
  <element>
    <text_attribute>Some more Text</text_attribute>
    <attribute var="blah again"/>
    <bool_attribute><boolean.false/></bool_attribute>
  </element>
</root>
```

And get something like this:

```
[
   { "text_attribute":"Some Text", "attribute":"blah", "bool_attribute":True },
   { "text_attribute":"Some more Text", "attribute":"blah again", "bool_attribute":False }
]
```

To do this I'd do something like this (untested):

```
# Helper function so we can extract a default from an xpath result if empty
def get_first(x, default_value):
  if(len(x)>0) return x[0]
  return default_value

# Parse one element
def process_element( e ):
  retval = {}
  retval['text_attribute'] = get_first(e.xpath("text_attribute/text()"), "default text")
  retval['attribute'] = get_first( e.xpath("attribute/@var"), "default attribute")
  retval['bool_attribute'] = get_first( e.xpath("bool_attribute/boolean.true"), False )
  return retval

# Parse all the elements
elements = []
elements_xml = xml.xpath('/root/element')
for e in elements_xml:
  elements.push( process_element(e) )
```